# Удаление нескольких записей по внешнему ключу с проверкой данных

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с заданием и прошу помочь решить его. Так вот, необходимо удалить данные об сотруднике, при этом нужно проверить нет ли запланированных процедур на данного работника, и если есть невыполненные процедуры, необходимо вернуть ее стоимость на счет клиента. Я тут накидал нечто, но может есть какие-либо более приемлемые варианты, т.к. данный запрос зацикливается.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `RemovePersonnel`(
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
id CHAR(36)
)
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS (SELECT * FROM clientprocedures WHERE clientprocedures.IdPersonnel = id);
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM temp) DO
        SELECT @CostOldClientProcedure := temp.Cost, @IdOldClient := temp.IdClient, @DateClientProcedure := temp.Date FROM temp WHERE temp.Id = Id;
        IF (@DateClientProcedure > now()) THEN
        UPDATE client
        SET Balance = Balance + @CostOldClientProcedure
        WHERE client.Id = @IdOldClient;
        END IF;

        IF @@error_count = 0 THEN
        commit;
        ELSE rollback;
        END IF;
        DELETE FROM temp WHERE temp.Id = Id;
    END WHILE;
    DELETE FROM personnel WHERE personnel.Id = id;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *Никогда* не называйте параметры функции так же как называется хотя бы одна колонка в хотя бы одной таблице, используемой в процедуре. Ибо компилятор не сможет их отличить. Судя по всему в вас в clientprocedures есть колонка ID и ваш первый запрос трактуется компилятором так:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM clientprocedures
    WHERE clientprocedures.IdPersonnel = clientprocedures.id
   ```

   Какие записи он так выберет предсказать сложно.
2. У вас ошибка в строке `select ... from temp WHERE temp.Id = Id`, во первых тут та же проблема что в п.1, во вторых у вас в переменной id, даже если бы она использовалась,все еще содержится параметр переданный в функцию и очень вероятно, что select не возвращает ни одной строки (отсюда и зацикливание).
3. SQL мощный язык. Использовать курсоры, последовательно перебирающие записи в таблице надо только в очень экзотических ситуациях. Практически любые задачи можно решить единичным запросом. Весь ваш цикл отлично заменяется одним запросом, причем без использования каких бы то ни было временных таблиц:

   ```
   update client C
    inner join(
      select IdClient, sum(Cost) as Cost
        from clientprocedures
       where IdPersonnel = NNN and Date > now()
       group by IdClient
    ) B on C.id=B.IdClient
      set C.Balance=C.Balance+B.Cost
   ```